# Password resetting > request redirects to login

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

config.yml

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: Portal\UserBundle\Entity\User
    registration:
        confirmation:
            enabled: true
        form:
            type: Portal\UserBundle\Form\RegistrationType
    from_email:
        address: "%mailer_user%"
        sender_name: "%mailer_user%"
```

When I click on the password reset button, I am forwarded to the login. Button's Route:

```
<a href="{{ path('fos_user_resetting_request') }}" class="__input __button">{{ 'resetting.reset.submit'|trans }}</a>
```

It looks like a bug - I have no special configuration, only this. FOSUserBundle version is v2.1.2.

Comment: On your security settings, in access_control the role of the resetting request path is IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY?

Answer (score 0):

your route "fos_user_resetting_request" must be able to visit anonymously, check that you do not have any security clause in this route [[example @security("has_role('any')") ]], remember to have this route in a firewall that allows anonymous visits

like:

```
firewalls:
    database_security:
        anonymous: ~
        pattern: ^/
```